# fb friend selector & php POST formular not working properly

Tags: facebook, http-post, facebook-wall

Hey guys,
I've used the search as well so I am confident in asking the question here without doing anything wrong :P

Recently I was developing for fun and learning purposes another Facebook application! Basically what I want it to do is:

1.) You choose something to click on
2.) You choose from the fb friend selector formular one friend

and then the app does a wall posting with the item chosen at point 1 on the wall of the friend chosen from point 2!

The thing is, i created a php post formular and had the fb friend selector in it like that:

```
<form action="send.php" id="testForm" method="post">

[blah blah the items to choose]

    <fb:serverfbml style="width: 240px; height: 700px;"> 
<script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml> 
<fb:friend-selector uid="$user" name="uid" idname="uid2"/>
    </fb:fbml>
</script> 
</fb:serverfbml>

<input class="inputbutton" style="cursor: pointer;" name="do_it" value="submit" type="submit">

</form>
```

So the thing is, when my send.php file only contains for example:

```
<?php
```

[facebook api shit]

```
 if($_POST[do_it]=="submit"){
     echo $_POST[$user];
 }
```

or i replaced it with echo $_POST['uid'] or $_POST['uid2']

and none of them showed me a value at all

so where is the bug??

Answer (score 0):

fb:serverfbml creates an iframe, so because your form is outside, it won't send anything inside the fb:serverfbml tag.
You need to do something like this:

```
<fb:serverfbml width="615">
 <script type="text/fbml">
   <form name="form" action="http://www.remy-mellet.com/remote/fb/reverse/temp.php" id="form">        
        <fb:friend-selector uid="797350112" name="uid" idname="friend"/>
        <INPUT type="submit" value="test">
      </form>
  </script>

</fb:serverfbml>
```

Parameters received:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
?>
```